# Error connecting to a database in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form from which values are submitted to database. But I'm not able to connect to it, and don't know why.

On submit, there is no response from localhost.

Here is my HTML layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Student Entry</h1>
        <form action="new.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit"></td>
                <td><input type="reset"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
     $id = $_POST["id"];
     $name = $_POST["name"];
     echo $id,$name;
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost:81","root","");
     if(!$con) {
        echo "could not connect".mysqli_connect_error();
     }
     echo 'connection success';
     mysqli_select_db($con,"student");
     mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO info (id,name) VALUES ($id,$name)");
     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: the database is created manually in phpmyadmin

Comment: Any reason you're specifying port 81 to connect to? If not, remove `:81` from your connection call.

Comment: What is the output when you input the form? What is the connect error?

Comment: Are you sure the database is running? Can you execute a query with a command line tool like `mysql`?

Comment: Note, your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should be using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with mysqli.

Comment: @scrowler: i am using port 81 because IIS is configured on port 80.

Comment: i am not able to get any output.It is saying waiting for localhost but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely not connecting to the MySQL server, but to just nothing instead.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:81","root","");
```

Please [see the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php) about the passable parameters to this function. The first parameter must be a hostname and only a hostname. In your case this would be `localhost`. If you need to specify a port, you would pass it as **fifth** parameter.

Keep in mind that MySQL and IIS are completely independent from each other. The default port for IIS is 80. The default port for MySQL is 3306. These are completely independent and the softwares will always occupy the same port, independent of other installed applications.

You might want to try:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
```

If you want to specify a port, you must use:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "", 3306);
```

which connects to a default MySQL installation.

If your MySQL server really listens on a different port, for example because you changed the configuration accordingly, you can change the last parameter.